# Pushnotifications in not working on 2.3.3 and working on 4.x devices

Tags: android, push-notification

I wrote a push notification sample with the help of this doc http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html. It's working on 4.x devices and not working on 2.3.3 devices.

here is my permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.testing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testing.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTRATION" />


   <receiver
        android:name="com.example.testing.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.testing" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

Comment: What error are you getting on 2.3.3 devices? Post your Logcat

Comment: could you be please more precise what error are you getting? it is the same as saying "my app doesn't work, what is wrong?"

Comment: in onReceive()     String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent); always returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the documentation :

> The android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS permission as GCM requires a Google account (necessary only if if the device is running a version lower than Android 4.0.4)

This permission is not in the examples.

Comment: Yes i added that permission.